# Why won't my Delphi accept anything under a private declaration?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am a student and Delphi is not really my primary environment for programming. I know how it works and I'm completely familiar with its layout. I recently received a task in which I have to use arrays in order to list them in a listbox via integer and string. The idea is very simple and the program itself is very easy to make.

The problem comes when I try to declare a constant under the private or public it just shows and error message stating "'END' expected but 'CONST' found". I have worked with public and private variables and constants for a while now but I'm not really sure what's going on.

The code is as follows:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    edtDateTime: TEdit;
    lstListArrayValues: TListBox;
    gbpIntegerArrayOptions: TGroupBox;
    gbpStringArrayOptions: TGroupBox;
    gbpListBoxOptions: TGroupBox;
    btnInitializeIntArray: TButton;
    btnAssignIntArray: TButton;
    btnDoubleIntArray: TButton;
    btnInitializeStrArray: TButton;
    btnAssignStrArray: TButton;
    btnCapitalStrArray: TButton;
    btnDisplayArray: TButton;
    btnClearListbox: TButton;
    btnDeleteSelected: TButton;
    XPManifest1: TXPManifest;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnInitializeIntArrayClick(Sender: TObject);

    private
    {Private Declarations}
      Const
        nItems = 5;
      var
        nBasicsIntArray : array [0..(nItems - 1)] of integer;
        nBasicsStrArray : array [0..(nItems - 1)] of string;
    public
      { Public declarations }
  end;
```

When I run the application it says "'END' expected but 'CONST' found". I am using Windows 7 and Delphi 7 and I have not had this problem before.

It could honestly be that I'm missing something stupid but I've overlooked everything and I can't seem to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: Class constants are not allowed in Delphi 7. It was introduced later.

Comment: See [Enums vs Const vs Class Const in Delphi programming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/382234/576719). It seems class constants was introduced in D2005 or even in .NET D8.

Comment: Correction, the feature matrix in BDS2006 says `New for Delphi Win32! Class variables/class static data`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ability to declare constants inside a class was not supported in Delphi 7. That language feature was added in a later release.

Declare your constant outside the class.

The same is true of your use of `var`. That syntax is not supported in Delphi 7. You should simply remove the `var` keyword from your class declaration.

Comment: In addition, the `var` keyword doesn't belong in the class declaration in Delphi 7 either, as there was no `class var` support.

Comment: @Ken That's not a class var, it's an instance var. I'm not sure whether or not it is valid in d7. Will need to check.

Comment: @David: No, not in Delphi 7. No `var`, no `const`, no `type` inside a class declaration. Those were added in Delphi 8 for the .NET compiler and then in Delphi 2005 and 2006 for the native compiler.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks. I realised that when I tried it.

Comment: @David: I couldn't try it, if I wanted. No Delphi 7 installed anymore. The lowest is 2007 (for my Delphi for .NET project), otherwise only the XE ones.

Answer (score 1):

As written above, a solution can be to move your local constant to global position under Delphi 7.
Here is a code sample:

```
Const
    nItems = 5;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    edtDateTime: TEdit;
//...
  private
      nBasicsIntArray : array [0..(nItems - 1)] of integer;
      nBasicsStrArray : array [0..(nItems - 1)] of string;
//...
  end;
```

*Also you can use "**const**" and "**type**" keywords multiple times to keep things together.*

Comment: I fail to see where your answer differs from the accepted solution.

Comment: @nil: You are right, just wanted to add a simplified code example, and a hint for multiple usage of the keywords. Edited accordingly.